# is it possible to use QtConcurrent::run() with a function member of a class

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

I can't seem to be able to associate `QtConcurrent::run()` with a method (function member of a class) only with a simple function.  How can I do this?

With a regular function I cannot emit  signals and its a drag.  Why would anyone find this a better alternative to `QThread` is beyond me and would like some input.

Comment: Note that while you may emit a signal in a thread, using either method, it may not create widgets.  Only the main GUI thread may.  Also, the main GUI thread will likely need to process the signal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (and quite easy).

Here is an example (from the Qt documentation):

```
// call 'QStringList QString::split(const QString &sep, SplitBehavior behavior, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs) const' in a separate thread
QString string = ...;
QFuture<QStringList> future = QtConcurrent::run(string, &QString::split, QString(", "), QString::KeepEmptyParts, Qt::CaseSensitive);
...
QStringList result = future.result();
```

Basically, all you have to do is pass a pointer to the object as the first argument and the address of the method as the second argument (followed by any other arguments).

See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html

Comment: One thing that cost me some time is that QtConcurrent does not like overloaded functions :D

Comment: `pass a pointer` -- note, that `string` in your example is not (but should be, I guess) ;)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that when you use a pointer to member function, you need to somehow provide the `this` parameter also (i.e., the object on which the member function should be called).

The syntax for this is quite difficult if you haven't used it before.  It might be good to read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html .

Say you have a class `Dog` and a function `Dog::walkTheDog(int howlong_minutes)`.  Then you ought to be able to use `std::bind1st` and `std::mem_fun` to make it suitable for `QtConcurrent::run`:

```
Dog dog;
// Walk this dog for 30 minutes
QtConcurrent::run(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Dog::walkTheDog), &dog), 30);
```

`std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Dog::walkTheDog), &dog)` returns a function-like object which has bound the member function to a particular dog.  From that point you can use it much like you could use a standalone function.

Comment: can you please look at this question, I have faced such problem,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792153/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-qtconcurrent?noredirect=1#comment82546866_47792153